# How can I pass the index from javascript map function to the onclick function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of data that I'm iterating through, In the javascript map() function call I'm using the second argument that map() takes, 'index'. How would I pass index to the onClick event? I tried adding index to the list of arguments for onClick but all I can access are the events. Is there anyway I can pass the index through?

I'd like to be able to execute the commented out line 'handleImageClick(productObjects[index])'. I need to let the parent component know which productObject was clicked on by the user.

```
export default function SideProducts(props) {
    
const { productObjects, handleImageClick } = props;


const onClick = (e) => {
    e.persist()
    console.log(e)
    //handleImageClick(productObjects[index])
}

console.log(productObjects)
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            {productObjects.map((productObject,index) => (
                <ImageWrapper key={index} src={productObject.image} onClick={(e) => onClick(e)}>
                    
                </ImageWrapper>
            ))}
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am doing this without testing, but you should be able to just pass the index like this.

```
const onClick = (e, index) => {
    e.persist()
    console.log(e)
    //handleImageClick(productObjects[index])
}

console.log(productObjects)
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            {productObjects.map((productObject,index) => (
                <ImageWrapper key={index} src={productObject.image} onClick={(e) => onClick(e, index)}>
                    
                </ImageWrapper>
            ))}
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This way.
please go through this blog to learn more about passing arguments with [onClick](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/pass-a-parameter-through-onclick-in-react)

```
export default function SideProducts(props) {
    
const { productObjects, handleImageClick } = props;


const onClick = (e, index) => {
    e.persist()
    console.log(e, index)
    //handleImageClick(productObjects[index])
}

console.log(productObjects)
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            {productObjects.map((productObject,index) => (
                <ImageWrapper key={index} src={productObject.image} onClick={(e) => onClick(e, index)}>
                    
                </ImageWrapper>
            ))}
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to pass the `index` as argument.
   `onClick={(e) => onClick(e, index)}`
2. Then receive that index as functional parameter.

```
const onClick = (e, index) => {
    e.persist()
    console.log(e, index)
    //handleImageClick(productObjects[index])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it as a parameter to yow onClick

```
        <ImageWrapper key={index} src={productObject.image} onClick={(e) => onClick(e,productObject.addThePropHere)}>
                    
                </ImageWrapper>
```

Then in your function just add it as well

const onClick = (e,prop)=> ….code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a higher-order function here to pass params as you want:

```js
const handleWithIndex= index => {
    return (event) => {
         e.persist()
         //handleImageClick(productObjects[index])
    }
}

return (
        <Wrapper>
            {productObjects.map((productObject,index) => (
                <ImageWrapper key={index} src={productObject.image} onClick={handleWithIndex(index)}>
                    
                </ImageWrapper>
            ))}
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```